# Using same OAuth details for iOS and Android app

Tags: android, ios, oauth

I have an OAuth client key value as - 1234 => "randomstring"; (My own API)

This is being used in my iOS app so that it can authenticate my application correctly and send in details as needed.

My question is - can I use the same details as above to authenticate my Android application as well ,ie, it would use the same credentials as a request using the same app client credentials - so that I could request details on my Android app as I do on the iOS app as well ?

Or is there another approach for this?

Comment: Yes since you have not put check in server.
Server has nothing to do with who sending requesting. It just takes the request and send the response.

Comment: In case there is a check? Would it not be possible to keep both apps with the same details?

Comment: If there is a check in server then in your request you need to send some flag which uniquely identifies whether it is from Android or iOS.